# Pokemon Alpha Sapphire missed HM03 Surf

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I missed the HM03 Surf after the gym battle and now I can't find a way to progress in the game.

Where can I get it? The guy who is supposed to give it to me, which is in the house next to the gym, now just says that his son Wally is not there anymore

Now I'm stuck and can't find a way to learn this move.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure you have the Balance Badge, but don't already have HM03? I seem to remember being given it automatically after leaving the Gym.

Comment: I don't have it. But when I talk to the guy on the gym he just says that i've gotten stronger and the 2 doors behind him are locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need to collect 5 badges before you get HM03

When you first arrive in Petalburg City, you're not able to challenge the gym leader there, who tells you to come back once you have 4 other badges. Only once you have done that and returned to beat the Petalburg Gym, getting the Balance Badge, will you be given HM03. You'll know you've reached this point when your trainer card shows the appropriate badges and the doors at the back of the first room of the Gym are unlocked.

If this is your first time in Petalburg, having just defeated Wally for the first time, you should continue to the northwest towards Rustboro, then eventually to the southwest to speak to Mr. Briney to reach Dewford.

Comment: That was the problem, I've missed the cable car in the topmost city, so I thought that the correct path was to use surf to go east, but I had just 3 badges.

I've collected the other badges and was able to get it now, thanks.